# What's the best way to create PDFs?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm building a web app that needs to produce some PDF documents. Regardless of language and platform, what's the best way to generate excellent quality PDFs?

I was originally doing HTML and wkhtml2pdf but I'm not sure this will deal with pagination and cleanly wrapping multi page tables. I'm happy to use any tech like Word, Acrobat, etc so long as it can be automated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the well supported https://tcpdf.org/